# Unable to start component info DatePicker

Tags: android

I am working with Tabs and also using multiple activities with single Tab. 
i am facing a problem i.e when i go from parent class to child class that class has datepicker  in it and click on button that shows dialogue of date from where date can b selected. But when i click on that button (that triggers the date dialogue) my application crashes 
when the following 
"Unable to Start component info"
need help to resolve this

here is subactivity code

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {
    private TextView tvDisplayDate,personName,Cname,cAdrress;
    private DatePicker dpResult;
    private Button btnChangeDate;
    Button cancel;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.placeorder);
        personName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        Cname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Cname);
        cAdrress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAddname);
        personName.setText(AccountInfo.fnameNlName);
        Cname.setText(AccountInfo.cName);
        cAdrress.setText(AccountInfo.cAdd);
        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Cancel);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==1) 
                {
                    Intent fastPkgQuote = new Intent(v.getContext(), FastPkgQuote.class);
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    FastPkgQuote parentActivity = (FastPkgQuote)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView("fastpkg1", fastPkgQuote);
                }
                else if(FastPkgMainActivity.fastPackge==2)
                {
                    Intent fastpkgQuoteNew = new Intent(v.getContext(), FastPkgQuoteNew.class);
                    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
                    FastPkgQuoteNew parentActivity = (FastPkgQuoteNew)getParent();
                    parentActivity.replaceContentView1("fastPkg2", fastpkgQuoteNew);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
        dpResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) 
            {
                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;
                tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));
                // set selected date into datepicker also
                dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

here is logcat result

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 

Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44ef0838 

is not valid; is your activity running?


android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)

04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.show(DatePickerDialog.java:129)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2556)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2514)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at corrculator.fastPkg.PlaceOrder$3.onClick(PlaceOrder.java:108)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-20 15:50:06.703: E/AndroidRuntime(323):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code and the LogCat error statements?

Comment: here is activity rather subactivity code with logcat results

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181432/android-alertdialog-box-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem could be on this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Try modifying it to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivityName.this);
```