# Spinner dynamic error

Tags: android, spinner

I have an error in my app for Android. I have a class `LineaArticulo` dynamics to form a line with labels, edit text, a button and spinner, to tighten the spinner I get an error, attached here the class constructor.

All data is the correct.

Here just put the spinner case.

```
public LineaArticulo(RelativeLayout layoutactual, final String[] Casos, Context context, int Xspinner, int Yspinner){

    final Spinner spiner = new Spinner(context);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Casos);

    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spiner.setAdapter(adaptador);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramSpiner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramSpiner.leftMargin = Xspinner; // Your X coordinate
    paramSpiner.topMargin = Yspinner; // Your Y coordinate
    spiner.setLayoutParams(paramSpiner);

    layoutactual.addView(spiner);
}
```

Error:

```
  06-04 16:02:02.021      961-961/compra.online.mercavalencia    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
    at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:260)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your variable `contexto` is `null`

Comment: I've tried and the error keeps coming

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should use application `Context` for toasts and `Activity` for dialogs.

You problem is, as it says, in `AlertDialog`, which is used internally in `Spinner`.

> AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)

[Similar entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181432/android-alertdialog-box-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-problem)

Comment: When I pass the context constructor with this line

           Context contexto = Quinta.this.getApplicationContext();

"Quinta" is the kind where I create the spinner

Comment: edited the answer. If it doesnt help try googling dialog construction issue.

Comment: I came here for people who know about this I answer and tell me to look in google ... thank you very much